# composer update -v display an error : [ErrorException] preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, composer-php, preg-match

I am hosting my laravel 8 project. When I execute the command composer update -v and also other commands with composer in my Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS server, the errors  below are displayed

```
             [ErrorException]
              preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given
              
            Exception trace:
             () at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/IO/BaseIO.php:127
             Composer\Util\ErrorHandler::handle() at n/a:n/a
             preg_match() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/IO/BaseIO.php:127
             Composer\IO\BaseIO->loadConfiguration() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Factory.php:337
             Composer\Factory->createComposer() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Factory.php:595
             Composer\Factory::create() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Console/Application.php:409
             Composer\Console\Application->getComposer() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Console/Application.php:527
             Composer\Console\Application->getPluginCommands() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Console/Application.php:187
             Composer\Console\Application->doRun() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:117
             Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Console/Application.php:122
             Composer\Console\Application->run() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/bin/composer:63
             require() at /usr/local/bin/composer:24
```

this is my composer.json

```json
 {
    "name": "bedigit/laraclassified",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "Classified Ads Web Application.",
    "keywords": [
        "ads",
        "classified",
        "cms",
        "laravel",
        "php"
    ],
    "license": "Envato",
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://github.com/bedigit/laravel-meta-tags"
        },
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://github.com/bedigit/EloquentDataTable"
        },
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://github.com/bedigit/omnipay-payu"
        },
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://github.com/bedigit/guzzle6-adapter"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.3",
        "ext-curl": "*",
        "ext-json": "*",
        "aws/aws-sdk-php": "~3.0",
        "bedigit/lara-recaptcha": "^1.1",
        "bileto/omnipay-payu": "dev-master",
        "chriskonnertz/open-graph": "~2",
        "cocur/slugify": "^4.0",
        "creativeorange/gravatar": "~1.0",
        "cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable": "^8.0",
        "doctrine/dbal": "^2.10",
        "fakerphp/faker": "^1.11.0",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.2",
        "florianv/laravel-swap": "^2.0",
        "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0",
        "graham-campbell/flysystem": "^7.1",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.0.1",
        "ignited/laravel-omnipay": "^3.3",
        "intervention/image": "^2.5",
        "iyzico/iyzipay-php": "^2.0",
        "jackiedo/dotenv-editor": "1.*",
        "jaybizzle/crawler-detect": "1.*",
        "jaybizzle/laravel-crawler-detect": "1.*",
        "lab404/laravel-impersonate": "^1.7",
        "laracasts/flash": "^3.2",
        "laravel-notification-channels/twilio": "^3.1",
        "laravel/framework": "^8.0",
        "laravel/helpers": "^1.3",
        "laravel/nexmo-notification-channel": "^2.4",
        "laravel/passport": "^10.0",
        "laravel/slack-notification-channel": "^2.2",
        "laravel/socialite": "^5.0",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.0",
        "laravelcollective/html": "^6.2",
        "league/csv": "^9.6",
        "league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3": "^1.0",
        "league/flysystem-cached-adapter": "^1.0",
        "league/flysystem-sftp": "^1.0",
        "livecontrol/eloquent-datatable": "dev-master",
        "mews/purifier": "3.3.*",
        "mhetreramesh/flysystem-backblaze": "^1.5",
        "omnipay/paypal": "~3.0@dev",
        "omnipay/stripe": "~3.1@dev",
        "php-http/guzzle6-adapter": "^2.0",
        "php-http/message": "^1.7",
        "predis/predis": "^1.1",
        "prologue/alerts": "^0.4.8",
        "propaganistas/laravel-phone": "4.*",
        "pulkitjalan/geoip": "5.*",
        "spatie/flysystem-dropbox": "^1.2",
        "spatie/laravel-backup": "^6.11",
        "spatie/laravel-cookie-consent": "^2.12",
        "spatie/laravel-feed": "^2.7",
        "spatie/laravel-permission": "^3.17",
        "spatie/laravel-translatable": "^4.6",
        "therobfonz/laravel-mandrill-driver": "^3.0",
        "torann/laravel-meta-tags": "dev-master",
        "unicodeveloper/laravel-password": "1.0.*",
        "unicodeveloper/laravel-paystack": "1.0.*",
        "vemcogroup/laravel-sparkpost-driver": "^4.0",
        "watson/sitemap": "4.0.*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "facade/ignition": "^2.3.6",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.3.1",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^5.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "files": [
            "app/Helpers/Functions/admin.php",
            "app/Helpers/Functions/core.php",
            "app/Helpers/Functions/plugin.php",
            "app/Helpers/Functions/wordpress.php"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/",
            "extras\\": "extras/",
            "LarapenIlluminate\\": "packages/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/",
            "Larapen\\TextToImage\\": "packages/larapen/texttoimage/src/",
            "Larapen\\Admin\\": "packages/larapen/admin/src/",
            "Larapen\\LaravelDistance\\": "packages/larapen/laravel-distance/src/",
            "Larapen\\Feed\\": "packages/spatie/laravel-feed/src/",
            "Larapen\\Impersonate\\": "packages/lab404/laravel-impersonate/src/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {},
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": [
                "lab404/laravel-impersonate",
                "mcamara/laravel-localization",
                "spatie/laravel-feed"
            ]
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ],
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "optimize-autoloader": true
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

Please help me i don't known how to do to solve it.

I deleted the vendor file, this did not solve the problem, I searched until I found a link https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/826 but nothing.

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of textual question details.

Comment: This might be a configuration issue. Can you share your composer.json (redact any personal info first)

Comment: Please add the composer version (`composer --version`) to the question ([edit]) and consider double and triple V to increase verbosity (`update -vv`, `update -vvv`), maybe you can spot the culprit already then. This looks like an unchecked error condition within composer itself while loading the configuration. Therefore what @apokryfos suggested sounds reasonable to me, too.

Comment: Please share more details, like the code involved to reproduce the problem

Comment: @apokryfos  i added the composer.json file

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @hakre , when i try composer --version the same error appear ([ErrorException] preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given)

Comment: @Nico Haase , i deleted all my vendor document and it try to update project , but nothing

Comment: @Nico Haase , when I type any command on the composer, the same error appears.

Comment: @Nico Haase I'm stuck on this error because I don't know the cause and how to solve it and moreover all the commands that I type with compose show the same error.

Comment: `composer --version` info is still missing in your question. [edit] in **all** the details.